# Lightswitch XtraReport chart - reducing number of points / accessing dataSource

Tags: c#, silverlight, devexpress, visual-studio-lightswitch, xtrareport

I have an XtraReport with 6 charts containing 4-8 LineSeries, where each Series can have up to 25,000 Points. The data comes from a query from a database table.

The problem is, that it takes around 3 minutes to draw the report which is too long for us.
So we need to reduce the number of points (which I already did in another case, so I know how to do that).

But where is the "right place" to perform this reducing action? Within the screen where the ReportPreview control is located and passing a new Collection (with all the series) as Parameter to the report? Is it possible to use such an custom Object as Parameter?

Or should I first load the database table inside the report and then reduce it?

How can I access the Datasource within the XtraReport by code?

And how can I tell my chart components to select my Collection as dataSource and not the database query result?

Also any other ways to improve the performance of XtraReports & charts.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

We created a SQL View which reduced the number of points and also used some code in the Preprocess_query methode with LINQ to use only needed points.